# How to call procedure with package type param in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

In oracle DB, I created a custom type in a package and i guess this type is similar to integer array.

```
create or replace PACKAGE mypackage AS 
   TYPE custom1 is table of integer index by binary_integer;
END mypackage;
```

Used type in procedure IN param  and expecting out param to be size of IN param.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE( param1 in mypackage.custom1, count1 out integer) IS
begin
count1 := param.count();
END MYPROCEDURE
```

Now I want to call above procedure,for this I should prepare mypackage.custom1.

Please help me in constructing mypackage.custom1 and call above procedure.

Comment: You can simply define some variables of the needed types and then call the procedure. What problem are you having?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Executing above procedure with list of integers passing to custom type

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT = ON;
declare
    v mypackage.custom1;
    n number;
begin
    v(0) := 10;
    v(1) := 12;
    v(2) := 14;
    v(3) := 16;  
    --
    MYPROCEDURE(v, n);
    dbms_output.put_line('n= ' || n);
end;
```

output :

```
n = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE mypackage AS
    TYPE custom1 IS TABLE OF INTEGER
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
END mypackage;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(param1 IN mypackage.custom1, count1 OUT INTEGER) IS
BEGIN
    count1    := param1.COUNT();
END MYPROCEDURE;
```

To call your procedure, you simply need to define two variables and call the procedure with them; for example, in an anonymous block:

```
declare
    v mypackage.custom1;
    n number;
begin
    select 1
    bulk collect into v
    from dual connect by level <= 5;    
    --
    MYPROCEDURE(v, n);
    dbms_output.put_line('n= ' || n);
end;

n= 5
```

The same way, you can build your stored procedures, packages, ... to call your procedure.

Comment: It worked,Thanks aleksej.Adding to this question, do you have idea on how to execute such procedures(procedures having custom types) through java.sql.CallableStatement in java ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the JDBC code to invoke above procedure

```
String procedure = "call MYPROCEDURE(?, ?)";
CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall(procedure);
ArrayDescriptor ad = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("mypackage.custom1", con);
ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(ad, con, new Integer[]{1,2,3,4});
callableStatement.setArray(1, arr);
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);

final boolean execute = callableStatement.execute();
System.out.println("No of entries :" + callableStatement.getObject(2));
```

**output :**

No of entries : 4